# Set project version from a taskKey

Tags: scala, versioning, sbt

I want to set project version which depends on the git branch, to have a current a major version + current date in development version and just major number in production. So i've made a task which computes the version i need:

```
val projectVersion = taskKey[String]("Compute project version")
projectVersion := {
  val v = version.value // get Major version number
  val date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date)
  if (isDev.value) v + "-" + date 
  else v
}
```

`isDev` is another task which return `Task[Boolean]` indicating wether this is a non master branch:

```
branch := Process("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD").lines.headOption
isDev  := branch.value != "master"
```

then i tried to set computed version to `version` key:

```
version      := Versioning.projectVersion.value
```

But it is forbidden:

```
BuildSettings.scala:15: A setting cannot depend on a task
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: How is `isDev` defined? As the error tells you, you'll have to figure out how to make `projectVersion` a `settingKey` instead of a `taskKey`. Also you seem to introduce a circular dependency (`projectVersion` depends on `version` and later `version` depends on `projectVersion`)

Comment: @0__ `projectVersion` should be a task either way i have to always call `reload`. As for the circular dependency i can change it with a simple variable where major version is saved, then not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can fix this without changing your *TaskKey* to a *SettingKey*.

However there is **already a plugin** which gives you most of what you need: [sbt-git](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git)

I tried the following: In `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.6.2")
```

Then `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
name := "Foo"

git.baseVersion := "1.0"

version := {
  val branch = git.gitCurrentBranch.value
  val isDev  = branch != "master"
  val v      = git.baseVersion.value
  val date   = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new java.util.Date)
  if (isDev) v + "-" + date
  else v
}
```

Running `sbt version` in master gives the short version, running in other branch gives dated version.

Comment: Thanx for the plugin! That's a nice solution